# Event not working with ParseControl method

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, dynamic-controls

I want to add dynamic image button on site without ID of Image button so I am using ASP tag to generate dynamic controls with ParseControl method, It's working but event is not fired when click on Image Button

Default.aspx.cs Code

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = @"<asp:ImageButton runat=server ImageUrl=""~/close-icon (1).png"" OnClick=""click"" />";
            Control c = Page.ParseControl(str);
            form1.Controls.Add(c);
        }


        protected void click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Image Clicl");
        }
```

Default.aspx Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to solve my problem by giving code in solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer, answer is below

Default.aspx.cs Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class dynamicimage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = @"<asp:ImageButton ID=""dynoimage"" ImageUrl=""~/images/about01.jpg"" runat=""server"" oncommand=""clickme"" commandname=""btn"" />";
        Control c = ParseControl(str);
        form1.Controls.Add(c);
        ((ImageButton)Page.FindControl("dynoimage")).Command += new CommandEventHandler(clickme);
    }

    protected void clickme(object sender,CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Image clicked");
        Label1.Text = "Image clicked";
    }
}
```

and here is the Default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dynamicimage.aspx.cs" Inherits="dynamicimage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="before click"></asp:Label>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```